# Backbone get set throws error after clone model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, lodash

I have customer model which has few details as shown below

```
customerModel.FIRST_NAME.get('value'); // this will give some name, works fine!
```

Now if i clone the model like below

```
 var cloneModel = _.cloneDeep(customerModel);
 cloneModel.FIRST_NAME.get('value'); 
 // This gives  Uncaught TypeError: cloneModel.FIRST_NAME.get is not a function
```

Kindly advise what am i missing here? why backbone get/set not works after clone?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want a new backbone model, why are doing a clone instead of creating new model instance with same data?

Answer (score 2):

Backbone get/set no longer work after a lodash _.cloneDeep because _.cloneDeep copies the properties of an object (i.e. the model's attributes), but not it's prototype. See below example:

```js
// Updating the prototype with new properties
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  myProperty: 'foo',
  myFunc: _.noop
});
var myModel = new MyModel({value: 'someValue'});
var cloneModel = _.cloneDeep(myModel);
console.log(myModel.get);
// ƒ (e){return this.attributes[e]}
console.log(myModel.myProperty);
// 'foo'
console.log(myModel.attributes.value);
// 'someValue'
console.log(cloneModel.get);
// undefined
console.log(cloneModel.myProperty);
// undefined
console.log(cloneModel.attributes.value);
// 'someValue'
```

What you want to use instead is [Backbone.Model's clone function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-clone).

```js
// Updating the prototype with new properties
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  myProperty: 'foo',
  myFunc: _.noop
});
var myModel = new MyModel({value: 'someValue'});
var cloneModel = myModel.clone();
console.log(myModel.get);
// ƒ (e){return this.attributes[e]}
console.log(myModel.myProperty);
// 'foo'
console.log(myModel.attributes.value);
// 'someValue'
console.log(cloneModel.get);
// ƒ (e){return this.attributes[e]}
console.log(cloneModel.myProperty);
// 'foo'
console.log(cloneModel.attributes.value);
// 'someValue'
```

This should be done in any case as even if _.cloneDeep worked as expected, you would have two instances of models with the same cid's, which can cause issues with eventing.